# CORS Error with Function App in Azure (new B2C Tennant)

Tags: asp.net, azure-functions, cors, azure-storage

I have an existing React app in Azure (hosted in a storage account) that's trying to make requests to an existing Function app (also in Azure). I'm getting this error in the browser console:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at <function-app-url>. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 401.
```

In the function app's CORS settings, 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' is checked, and the URL of the React app is listed as an allowed origin.

The URLs all look correct.

I can't see any CORS-specific code/config in either app, suggesting all the CORS config is done in Azure Portal.

Both the Function app and React app have been in place for some time but we have had to create a new B2C tennant since these apps were first deployed. Could that have caused things to stop working?

**Edit**: the code is very generic, using axios to make all api calls:

```
const response = await axios.request({ url, method, [dataOrParams]: data, timeout });
```

The OPTIONS/preflight request succeeds with 200 and the following headers:

Acces-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization,
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

The next request is the real one we make, which is a GET to the expected URL and it responds with 401 and a message "Invalid JWT". The Authorization header appears to be simply "Bearer". I would expect a token to be there too but it doesn't seem to be there.

The referrer policy for the GET request is set to **strict-origin-when-cross-origin**

So it looks like CORS errors, plus perhaps some token issue too?

Comment: Have you tried using * to allow all?

Comment: Edit your question and add the client code.

Comment: I've updated with a bit more info, hope it is useful. I can't specify * unfortunately since Azure doesn't allow * for the origin. It forces me to put in a URL